# How to log / trace method calls in Solidity

Tags: solidity, contract-debugging, testing, logs

Is there a way to know which methods were called/triggered during a run?

Sometimes a chain of methods are called within the smart contract (implicitly or explicitly) and it would be beneficial to know which ones were executed and which ones were not.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Remix IDE you can do something like this:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "hardhat/console.sol";

contract Demo{
    constructor(){
        console.log("hi");
    }
 }
```

Use console.log() in functions you need to see wether they are called.

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the tip. This may work for a single contract. But when I am working on a large project with tens of contracts calling each other, it would be hard to manually add (console.log()) on all methods.